# Query returns result even though subarray is not an exact match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a chat application. I have a conversation object that contains the members of that conversation. For example, a conversation between user_1 and user_2 is represented by a conversation object with a 'members' array field with reference ids to user_1 and user_2. My problem is it returns a result even if only 1 of the ids is in the query. Both ids should be present in the query and should return nothing if not.

I tried the methods for querying exact matches in arrays from here [Mongoose get docs matching the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22856201/6363888). Thus, I query like this:

```
 let conversation = await ConversationSchema.findOne({ '$and': [
   { 'members': { '$all': [ 'user1_id', 'user1_id' ] } },
   { 'members': { '$size': 2 } },
  ]});
```

The code above still returned the conversation object with [ 'user1_id','user2_id' ] as values for the members field. It should return null since it does not exist in my DB.

Comment: Both id's should be present in the query or *documents*? Also at the `$all` condition both fields that u query are `user1_id` and not `[ 'user1_id', 'user2_id' ]`

Comment: @ambianBeing both ids should be present in the query. I'm testing my query and ```'$all': [ 'user1_id', 'user1_id' ]``` should return **null**. But instead, it returns the first conversation that has  'user1_id' even though its member field contains ```[ 'user1_id', 'user2_id' ]```. Which is wrong because I expect the query to return something **only when there is an exact match** by using ```$all```.

Comment: What i'm looking for is it should get a result if it's ```[ 'user1_id','user2_id' ]``` or ```[ 'user2_id','user1_id' ]```. But it shouldn't get a result if it's ```[ 'user1_id','user1_id' ]```. Assume that my DB only contains 1 conversation and has  ```[ 'user1_id','user2_id' ]``` value on its members field.