# Mongoees query to find object with array of id's irrespective of their id's order - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
await Product.findOne({ features: ['5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0', '5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d']})
```

=> Null (it should return object)

```
await Product.find({ features: ['5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d', '5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0']})
```

=> Found Object

I want query so that irrespective order of ids in array I should get object and it's not matched results I want it to be specific results so found object should have only 2 keys any help?

```
await Product.find({ features: ['5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d', '5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0', 'a1a3fd5e209ea374df94d3e0']})
```

=> it should not be retun any result this query has two matching ids

This is result

```
{
  features: [ 5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d, 5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0 ],
  _id: 5ec5663756ca7576421628d8,
  __v: 1,
  created_at: 2020-05-20T17:17:43.342Z,
  updated_at: 2020-05-27T15:33:07.672Z,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$in`.

```
await Product.find({ features: { $in: ['5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0', '5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d'] } })
```

This finds the product which has any of the supplied feature ids.

If you want to match the product which has all the supplied features, then you can use `$all` instead of `$in`.

```
await Product.find({ features: { $all: ['5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0', '5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d'] } })
```

**As commented below, `$all` won't work of the query is for 2 ids and there are more than two features. **

Another approach is to use `$and`.

```
await Product.find({ $and: [
   { features: '5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0'} , 
   { features: '5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d'} 
 ]
})
```

Since you want to limit the size to two, the final query would like,

```
await Product.find({ $and: [
   { features: '5e209ea374df9a1a3fd4d3e0'} , 
   { features: '5ec566ba1b81f05db31ae91d'} 
   { features: { $size: 2 } } 
 ]
})
```

Comment: FYI. This will not work in case we have 3 or more elements in the `features` and the $all operator has only 2 elements. It works only if both of them are of same size.

Comment: $in is not what we want here, with $all the issue is if any object has 3 ids out of which 2 ids are same as off my supplied id's it is also coming in results. But I need only exact matching of ids and length as well so if I am suppling two ids resultant object should have only 2 ids
Following issue which says you can pass array direclty 
db.collection.find({ "members": [ "some id 1", "some id 2" ] })
it will give me exact results, but issue is if `som id 2` comes at first then it will not work



`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856201/mongoose-get-docs-matching-the-array`

Comment: @VishalG Got it, I think you will have to use `$and` then.

Comment: @RobinCSamuel check I have added answer, Thanks for your quick help

Comment: @VishalG No worries, I've updated my answer as I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: can you add `{ "features": { "$size": 2 } }` as well it will make sure It will match to results having 2 length only