# Mongoose where value in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the below code to return all blogs where the blog author ID is equal to the ID of the first administrator (orgAdmin) in an array:

```
let officialBlogs = await Blog.find().where('author.id').equals(help.orgAdmins[0]);
```

But I can't work out how to adapt this code so I can return blogs where the author matches ANY of the administrators in the array (i.e. orgAdmin[0], orgAdmin[1], orgAdmin[2] etc. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose get docs matching the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856201/mongoose-get-docs-matching-the-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator to get things based on passed ids like this:

```
const ids = [];
help.orgAdmins.forEach(id => ids.push(id));

let officialBlogs = await Blog.find({author.id: { $in: ids }});
```

Comment: we can pass help.orgAdmins directly right? instead of 'ids'

Comment: Yes, you can do that too if they are always fixed or same numbers.